# How to rotate a 3D image using tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, 3d, tensor

I have a image tensor: [batch, height, width, depth, 3], and a angle tensor: [angleX, angleY, angleZ]. How can I use the angle to rotate the image? The tf.contrib.image.rotate only work for 2D image.

By the way, can I use the "Y-rotate(X, angle)" as the loss function? I am not sure whether the tensorflow can calculate the gradient of rotate function.

Comment: Still no answer on this? I am also in search of an answer to this question.

Answer (score -2):

There is a code in [github](https://github.com/kevinzakka/spatial-transformer-network) which is useful for rotate. However, it only work for 2D image.

Comment: OP already said that. So this is not an answer.